# ruby OR statement executes twice when both variables are true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

I have a simple statement that executes if at least one of two variables are true. The problem I am having is if both variables are true the statement is executed twice. I only need it to execute once.

```
<% if intensity == "true" || @planned_intensity == "true" %>
  <div class="red_dot"></div>
<% end %>
```

Am I missing something obvious here? In the case where both variables are true I get two red dots.

//edit

It appears to be somewhere else but I cant seem to find the issue, here is the entire block:

```
<% LogEntry.cal_entry(entry_date.to_date, @athlete.id).each do |entry| -%>
  <% workouts = entry.workouts -%>
  <% workouts.each do |workout| -%>
    <% @planned_intensity = false %>
    <% planned_workouts = workout.planned_workouts -%>
    <% planned_workouts.each do |pworkout| -%>
      <% @planned_times = pworkout.planned_workout_times -%>
      <% @planned_times.each do |planned_time| -%>
        <% if planned_time.zone > 1 %>
          <% @planned_intensity = true %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

  <% completed_workouts = workout.completed_workouts -%>
  <% completed_workouts.each do |completed_workout| -%>
    <li id="<%= workout.id.to_s() %>">
    <% completed_workout.workout_times.each do |time| -%>
      <% intensity = "true" %>
      <% if time.zone > 1 %>
        <% intensity = true %>
      <% else %>
        <% intensity = false %>
      <% end %>
      <% if intensity == "true" || @planned_intensity == true %>
          <div class="red_dot"></div>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
      <%= link_to_coaches_dialog workout.activity_id, entry.id.to_s(), "edit", "cal", @athlete.id.to_s, workout.id.to_s(), entry_date.to_date.to_s() %>
      <% total_duration = 0 %>
      <% completed_workout.workout_times.each do |workout_time| -%>
        <% total_duration += workout_time.duration %>
      <% end -%>
      <% total_planned_duration = 0 %>
      <% @planned_times.each do |planned_time| %>
        <% total_planned_duration += planned_time.duration %>
      <% end %>
      <%= time_cleanup(total_duration/60) %>
      <% unless total_planned_duration == 0 %>
      <span class="smaller"> / 
      <%= time_cleanup(total_planned_duration/60) %></span>
      <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end -%>
  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: Why do you have `true` as a string ?

Comment: Something is going on elsewhere.

Comment: k I will add more info, not sure why I used a string.

Comment: Can you include the data that populates this view? Maybe your `completed_workout` has multiple `workout_times`?

Comment: Your `if` statement for the red_dot div is inside the `completed_workout.workout_times.each do |time|` loop. Are the multiple divs you're seeing just caused by going round this loop twice? (i.e. if `completed_workout.workout_times` contains 2 entries)

Comment: absolutely right, I should have noticed that, I really didn't need that statement inside the completed_workouts loop, upon moving it out the code worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Would you like to put that in an answer mike or will and I can give you the credit?

Comment: I'm happy for @willoller to post his comment as an answer and for you to upvote/accept that. Matt's answer is also good.

Comment: ouch negative vote, guess I should have seen the answer, wont make these mistakes again!

Comment: Solution was trivial _and_ unlikely to be of use to future searchers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell from looking at this exactly what could be causing the red dot to appear twice. I'd imagine the containing loop is running twice, but we have no idea what data is in the `workout_times`.

The real problem is that you are setting the values for `intensity` and `@planned_intensity` in this view code. You ought to really be doing logic like this in the model or controller. This layer (HTML view templates) is just for presentation. The reason for the separation is so that you don't get hard to pinpoint bugs like this one :)

I'd refactor so that the view calls a method on a `workout_time` object, so that the logic is then in this method. At least then you'll know where to look. You can also unit test this method, whereas testing this view will be awkward.

What models do you have right now? I'd imagine you should have `workout` and `workout_time`, then add `completed?` and `planned?` methods on the `workout` model and a `has_intensity?` method on `workout_time`.

Comment: thanks Matt, Perfect I will add that method to the workout_times model. I am realizing my organization of the workout models is repetitive since I have two models named completed_workouts and planned_workouts, even though the fields are largely similar. I will combine these models and simply put a boolean planned field, making it easy to filter planned and completed. Thanks everyone!